# I'm not able to login wtih oauth single sign on in react

Tags: reactjs, oauth, single-sign-on, okta

I'm getting a following error for user authentication via oauth in react,

```
auth ERROR:  Error: Subject (sub) claim must be a string present in the ID token
    at yi (jwt.ts:83:11)
    at e.<anonymous> (Auth0Client.ts:380:12)
    at tslib.es6.js:102:23
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:84:5)
    at o (tslib.es6.js:73:58)
    at nrWrapper (coi-react/?code=47hr2i32q34xx85rbif78mr2nk5bixk6exe3xdnygqdtoygl7e&state=dWF5NzlldjhyVnBVLmFQV3N1eC1tU0FCN1ZvLVJudG9VcjJlR0E5LWJmXw%3D%3D:6:14384). Below is my code I configured for react oauth
```

Below is my code for authentication using react, I dont know how to configure sub part as per the error?

```
<Auth0Provider
          audience={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_AUDIENCE!}
          domain={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN!}
          client_id={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_CLIENT_ID!}
          redirect_uri={redirectUri}
          onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
        >
return (
    <Auth0Context.Provider
      value={{
        isAuthenticated,
        user,
        loading,
        popupOpen,
        loginWithPopup,
        handleRedirectCallback,
        getIdTokenClaims: (...p) => auth0Client.getIdTokenClaims(...p),
        loginWithRedirect: (...p) =>
          auth0Client.loginWithRedirect({
            ...p,
          }),
        getTokenSilently: (...p) => auth0Client.getTokenSilently(...p),
        getTokenWithPopup: (...p) => auth0Client.getTokenWithPopup(...p),
        logout: (...p) => auth0Client.logout(...p),
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Context.Provider>
  );
```